# Numpy - Speed up iteration comparison?

Tags: python, numpy

The following use case:

I have a Numpy matrix/array with a few thousand 2d points. Call it A.
Eg:

```
[1 2]
[300 400]
..
[123 242]
```

I also have another Numpy matrix with a few 2d points as above. Call it `B`.

Basically, I want to iterate through `A`, then iterate through `B` and compute the distance between `A[i]` and `B[j]`. Then assign that back to another array. I could do it like this:

```
for i, (x0, x1) in enumerate(zip(A[:,0],A[:,1])):
    weight_distance = 0
    for j, (p0, p1) in enumerate(zip(A[:,0],A[:,1])):
        weight_distance = weight_distance + distance((p0,p1),(x0,x1))
    weight_array[i] = weight_distance
```

But this is too slow. What might be a Numpy way to approach this?

Comment: What is that function `distance`. Also, the code doesn't have `B` in it.

Comment: So you want to compute distance from all the points in `A` to all the points in `B`, if I'm correct? One simple thing would be to: `for i in range(len(A)): distances[i,:] = B - A[i,:]`. This is definitely going to be *a lot* faster than what you've done so far. Possibly you can get rid of iterating on `i`, but I don't know how off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is the code in `scipy.spatial.distance`, particularly the [cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) function. This can efficiently compute the pairwise distances between arrays of points for a wide variety of metrics.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

A = np.random.random((1000, 2))
B = np.random.random((100, 2))

D = cdist(A, B, metric='euclidean')
print(D.shape) # (1000, 100)

weights = D.sum(1)
print(weights.shape)  # (1000,)
```

Here `euclidean` is the standard root-sum-square distance that you're probably used to, and `D[i, j]` holds the distance between `A[i]` and `B[j]`, and so summing along axis 1 gives the desired weights.

There are ways to do this via broadcasting directly in numpy, but that approach would use several large temporary arrays, and will in general be slower than the scipy `cdist` approach.

---

Edit:
I thought I may as well add a note on the NumPy-only approach. It looks like this:

```
D2 = np.sqrt(((A[:, None, :] - B[None, :, :]) ** 2).sum(-1))
weights2 = D2.sum(1)
np.allclose(weights, weights2)  # True
```

Let's break it down:

- `A[:, None, :]` adds a new dimension to `A`, so its shape is now `[1000, 1, 2]`. Similar for `B[None, :, :]`, which becomes `[1, 100, 2]`
- `A[:, None, :] - B[None, :, :]` is a broadcasting operation which results in an array of differences, with shape `[1000, 100, 2]`
- We square every element of this result.
- the `sum(-1)` method on this result sums across the last dimension, resulting in an array of shape `[1000, 100]`
- we take the square root of the result, which gives the distance matrix
- we sum along axis 1 to get the weights

Notice that this broadcasting approach creates not one, but *two* temporary arrays of size `1000 * 100 * 2` along the way, which is why it is less efficient than a purpose-built compiled function like `cdist`.

Comment: With your scipy approach, how would you condense the D down to 1000 weight values, e.g. for each A[i], the sum of the distances to all the B[j] points, as requested by OP? Is that just weights = np.sum(D,axis=1)

Comment: Ah, I missed the sum there. Yes, that is how I would do it. ``weights = D.sum(1)``.